# Rails API, Devise & Mobile App.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, mobile, devise

I am designing a Rails application which will be consumed from a native mobile application. I am new to Rails and thus I feel a bit lost. I want to achieve the following:
•   Users of mobile application should be able to login using Facebook and invite their friends.
•   Users should be authorized in order to call the APIs.

To secure the APIs (I have read so many posts so far), I decided to do the following:
•   Use Devise gem on the service side with token_authenticatable to authenticate the client of the API i.e. my mobile app.

The workflow is as the following:
•   On client app: user logs-in using facebook and obtains a valid token.
•   On client app: Facebook token is sent to the service.
•   On the service: using FB graph I will make sure the user is real.
o   If they exist in my db, I will generate a token token for the api.
o   Else, I will add them to my db and generate a token for the api.
In my controllers, I am using `before_filter :authenticate_user!` but that seems to authenticate the user forever. My questions:
•   Is this the best way to do this?
•   What if the api token is intercepted? Other users will be able to make calls to the api using that token?
Any articles, books, casts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the [hartl tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)? It's pretty full with information. Once you have a working regular rails app you can research how to make it more API like which isn't hard. Check out [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem) for a place to start. Also while not free One Month Rails is simply amazing with their content and if you are seeking to get serious about web development, I can't recommend them strongly enough